# Failed to compile / Parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, {Component} from React;
import Ninjas from './Ninjas';
class App extends Component {
state = {
ninjas = {
{name:'qqq',age:'www',belt:'eee',id:1},
{name:'aaa',age:'sss',belt:'ddd',id:2},
{name:'zzz',age:'xxx',belt:'ccc', d:3}
]
}
render(){
<div className='App'>
<h1>My first app</h1>
<p>welcome</p>
<Ninjas ninjas={this.state.ninjas}/>
</div>
);
}
}
export default App;
```

> The code above is the main component and the code down bellow is component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Ninjas extends Component {
render(){
const {ninjas} = this.props;
const ninjaList = ninjas.map(ninja => {


return(
 <div className='ninja' key={ ninja.id }>
   <div>Name: { ninja.name }</div>
   <div>Age: { ninja.age }</div>
   <div>Belt: { ninja.belt }</div>
</div>
)
})
return(
<div className='ninja-list'>
{ninjaList}
</div>
)
}}
export default Ninjas;
```

> I'm following the some videos and all I get is this error. Failed to compile
>   ./src/App.js
>     Line 6:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: Your definition of ninjas is incorrect, it is `ninjas = {` insteam it should be `ninjas = [`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

You have made a syntax error.
As the error suggests check `line 6` in App.js. What do you see?

```
state = {
ninjas = {
{name:'qqq',age:'www',belt:'eee',id:1},
{name:'aaa',age:'sss',belt:'ddd',id:2},
{name:'zzz',age:'xxx',belt:'ccc', d:3}
]
}
```

The value that `state` holds has gross syntax errors.

**Solution**

Here is the corrected form,

```
    state = {
      ninjas: [
        { name: 'qqq', age: 'www', belt: 'eee', id: 1 },
        { name: 'aaa', age: 'sss', belt: 'ddd', id: 2 },
        { name: 'zzz', age: 'xxx', belt: 'ccc', d: 3 },
      ],
    };
```

**Explanation**

Here are the issues,

- First `ninjas` is a property inside `state` object but you are incorrectly providing it with a value using assignment operator(=), instead you should use `:`
- Next `ninjas` property holds an array of objects, you have mismatched the `[` with a curly brace `{`

If you understood what I pointed out then great, hopefully, you'll be on your way to create your app. If not then take a break from React and brush up on your fundamentals in Core JS. :)

Comment: [ the second error is next to this code id: 3, accidentally I made it while I wrote the code for reporting the problem.
And yes, thank you very much, I did not see the error, too many hours for the computer obviously. Once again, thank you very much. :D